# How to sort date and time in one column in a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, datetime, jtable

I want to sort something like LocalDateTime.

In my `JTable` I have values like:

> 30.10.2019 09:35:34 
>   12.09.2019 07:47:55 
>   12.09.2019 22:49:55 
>   24.09.2019 04:45:39

Now I want them to be sorted correctly like:

> 12.09.2019 07:47:55 
>   12.09.2019 22:49:55 
>   24.09.2019 04:45:39 
>   30.10.2019 09:35:34

I tried to customize my TableModel, but that wasn't successfull

```
@Override
public Class<?> getColumnClass(final int columnIndex)
{
    if (getColumnName(columnIndex).equals("Datecolumn")) return LocalDateTime.class;    
    try
    {
        return getValueAt(0, columnIndex).getClass();
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        return new String().getClass();
    }

}
```

`Date.class` or `new Date().getClass()` also doesn't work.

Maybe you have some tips for me?

### Update:

Finally I did it, so here is the solution:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
          TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(table.getModel());
          table.setRowSorter(sorter);
          int columnIndexToSort = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndex("Datecolumn");
          sorter.setComparator(columnIndexToSort, new Comparator<String>()
          {
             @Override
             public int compare(String o1, String o2)
             {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH:mm:ss");
                LocalDateTime ldt1, ldt2;
                ldt1 = LocalDateTime.parse(o1, formatter);
                ldt2 = LocalDateTime.parse(o2, formatter);
                return ldt1.compareTo(ldt2);
             }
          });
```

I know there are many other ways to solve this problem, but this was the first one which works fine for me.
This may help you:
 https://www.codejava.net/java-se/swing/6-techniques-for-sorting-jtable-you-should-know
 Any improvements?

Comment: Sorting can be achieved through TableModel usually. Have you debugged and are confident the column name is matching "Datecolumn"?

Comment: Does your column need to be editable?

Comment: tomgeraghty3: When I call the "getColumnClass"-Method the I get the correct class, but sorting doesn't work
Ole V.V: No it doesn't

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code some data to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three steps:

1. Put date-time objects in your data and/or table model, not strings.
2. Use a custom renderer for formatting the date-times in your cells.
3. As tomgeraghty3 already said, tell the table to auto-generate a row sorter.

### Put date-time objects in your data

Probably `Instant` objects are really most suitable for holding your data, but you can decide that better yourself. To keep this example simple, and only for this purpose, I am using `LocalDateTime` objects.

```
    Object[] columnNames = { "Date and time" };
    Object[][] data = {
            { LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.OCTOBER, 30, 9, 27) },
            { LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 26, 11, 25, 9) },
            { LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.OCTOBER, 4, 15, 54, 25) },
            { LocalDateTime.of(2019, Month.OCTOBER, 13, 9, 2, 29) }
    };
    table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
```

### Use a custom renderer

```
    table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new MyDateTimeRenderer());
```

As far as I had understood it should have been possible to specify `LocalDateTime.class` for the renderer to be used only for `LocalDateTime` objects, but this didn’t work for me, I don’t know why.

My `MyDateTimeRenderer` class looks like this:

```
public class MyDateTimeRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {

    private static DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.uuuu HH;mm;ss");

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        DefaultTableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer();
        String formattedDateTime = ((LocalDateTime) value).format(formatter);
        Component c = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table,
                formattedDateTime, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        return c;
    }

}
```

### Tell the table to auto-generate a row sorter

```
    table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

You may put this statement before or after the call to `setDefaultRenderer()`. I find it more natural to put it before.

### The result

Now the table looks like this before sorting:

[image]

Click on the column title “Date and time” to sort. Result:

[image]

Click once more to sort in the reverse order, descending:

[image]

### Link

[Using Custom Renderer with JTables](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~takebaya/ics111/jtable_custom/jtable_custom_renderer.html)

Comment: Thank you, that was a good answer, but when I tried your solution I find out, that my DateTime is stored as a string, by default. 
But that is no problem. I simply parse(and not format) my String.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the row sorter has been set:

```
table.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```